# Pass ref to function with looped id?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a very simple CMS that allows the user to update certain areas on the page.

I have a `h3` tag where I want to be able to pass a ref to my `onChange` function so that I can grab it's innerHTML text (that gets changed by contentEditable) and pass on the new data that gets changed to my back-end server. However, I'm having trouble being able to grab the innerHTML (of the new data) of the correct looped h3 that wants to get changed.

I read documentation online that ref would help me with this but it only gives me an example of where it does it in the render method instead of how to pass it to a function within the ref.

In short, I want to be able to modify my h3 tag (within the cms) with new data and send it to my back-end server to upload to my db.

Also, I tried playing around with not putting it inside of a function and I manage to get access to the `myRef.current` however in the console it shows as `null` I want to be able to get access to the specified ref's blogTopic Id so I know which mapped id I'm sending to my back-end server.

I have a lot of code so I'm only going to show the part where I'm stuck on:

```js
class Blogtopics extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      blogData: [],
      blogTopic: "",
    };
  }

  Selectblogtopics = async () => {
    const blogTopics = await blogtopicsService.selectblogTopics();

    this.setState({
      blogData: blogTopics
    });
  };

  editorData = (event, content) => {
    let data = content.getData();

    //this.setState({ blogContent: data });
  };

  onChange = (event, content) => {
    const node = this.myRef;
    //where im stuck
    console.log(node);
  };

  render() {
    const node = this.myRef;

    console.log(node);
    return (
      {this.state.blogData.map((rows, index) => (
        <div className="blogWrapper" key={uuid()}>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <h3
                suppressContentEditableWarning
                contentEditable={this.state.isEditing}
                style={
                  this.state.isEditing === true
                    ? { border: "1px solid #000", padding: "5px" }
                    : null
                }
                onInput={e => this.onChange(e)}
                ref={e => this.onChange(e, this.myRef)}
                //onBlur={e => this.onChange(e)}
              >
              {rows.blog_category}
        </div>
      ))}
    );
  }
}

export default Blogtopics;
```

Comment: why you don't do that as `ref={this.myRef}`?

Comment: Cause don't I need it inside of a function? What I'm trying to do is grab the innerHTML of my `h3` when the value gets changed (by the user within the cms). If I just do `ref={this.myRef}` it'll grab the ref when the component mounts immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onChange = (event) => {
  const nodeContent = this.myRef.current.innerHTML;
  console.log(nodeContent);
};

<h3 ... ref={this.myRef} onInput={this.onChange} ... >
```

will work. But since `onInput` passes target element you don't even need to use `ref`:

```
onChange = ({ target }) => {
    console.log(target.innerHTML);
}

<h3 onInput={this.onChange} >
```

Comment: Thank you I see what I was doing wrong. I forgot the `{}` inside of what I was trying to pass in my `onChange` function. Thank you! Not sure why I got downvoted so much. Maybe cause of the way I asked the question was unclear.